# SquareUp Request token: Forbidden

Tags: c#, square

I'm working in .NET 4.6.2 and had binding issues when trying to reference the Square.Connect library which is Standard 2.0 so I'm trying to manually code things.

```
public ActionResult RequestToken(string code)
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
{
    string baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/";

    SquareUpRequest squareUpRequest = new SquareUpRequest()
    {
        client_id = "Application ID (Not sandbox)",
        client_secret = "Personal Access Token",
        code = code
    };

    var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(baseUrl);
    var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("https://connect.squareup.com/oauth/token", RestSharp.Method.POST);
    request.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(squareUpRequest);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Client OAuthApplicationSecret");

    var response = client.Execute(request);
}


return View();
```

}

I'm assuming that I can request a token many times. SquareUpRequest is a custom class.

Do you seen anything incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I just noticed after a few hours of hell that:

```
 var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("https://connect.squareup.com/oauth/token", RestSharp.Method.POST);
```

should be

```
 var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/token", RestSharp.Method.POST);
```